# Find $a$ and $b$ such that sequence of functions converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) =a x^n +b $cos$(\frac {x}{n})$.
Find $a,b \in \bf R$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

I think that for existence of point wise limit of $f_n$ we've to assume that $a=0$ for $ \vert x \vert  >1$ and then point wise  limit is $b$ .For   $ \vert x \vert  <1$,again the limit is $b$ but we don't assume here that $a=0$.For $x=1$ ,limit is $a+b$ and at $x=-1$ limit does not exist.Is this correct ?How to proceed further?Do we need to consider separate cases ?